# How to return multi rows inside a list from relationship table?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am trying to pull related records from address table through main table. but when i run a query, i get following error: "Multiple rows returned with uselist=False for lazily-loaded attribute 'doctors.address'".

Any idea how i can loop and get all rows from related table ?

below is my result from query:
I have two records in address table pointing user_add_id. So, i want to see two address records related to that user id.

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "Contact_number": "12345678",
            "Email": "test@email.com",
            "address_id": {
                "city": "dallas",
                "id": 1,
                "latitude": "38",
                "longitude": "90",
                "state": "",
                "street_address": "test testse",
                "user_add_id": 10,
                "zip_code": "123353"
            },
            "experience": "5",
            "id": 6,
            "name": "venkat11",
            "photo": "http://127.0.0.1:5000//uploads/profilepic1.jpg",
            "selfDescription": "test",
            "sex": "male",
            "sirname": "g"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my class:

```py
class users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    sirname = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    sex = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    experience = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=False)
    selfDescription = db.Column(db.String(4000), unique=False)
    Contact_number = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=False)
    Email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    photo = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    address_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('address.user_add_id'), nullable=False)


class address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_add_id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False)
    street_address = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    state = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    zip_code = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False)
    latitude = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    longitude = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=False)
    user_add_rel = db.relationship('users', backref='address', lazy='joined')
```

I am using marshmallow nested.

class doctorsSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
class Meta:
model = users

```
id = ma.auto_field()
name = ma.auto_field()
sirname = ma.auto_field()
sex = ma.auto_field()
experience = ma.auto_field()
selfDescription = ma.auto_field()
Contact_number = ma.auto_field()
Email = ma.auto_field()
photo = ma.auto_field()
address_id = ma.Nested(addressDataSchema, attribute='address')
```

Comment: #flask After adding primary key to all fields in address table, i can get all records. Do you think this is best approach to do ?